# How to randomly select rows from Pandas dataframe based on a specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe, `df`, which has the following structure:-

```
         Column 1      Column 2 ....     Column 100
Row 1    0.233           0.555              0
Row 2    0.231           0.514              2
..
Row 15000    0.232           0.455          3
```

`Column 100` represents a particular class each row belongs to (which can be from `0-14`). Each category/class has `1000` rows associated to it. For each category (denoted by integers in `Column 100`), I only want to select `200` samples randomly, and create a new dataframe `df_new` which will have a new dimension of `15x200 = 3000 rows`. Any good way to reach this?

Comment: `df.groupby('Column 100').apply(lambda x:x.sample(200))` ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) per groups - then last column is sorted:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(15, size=(100000, 100)))
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Column {x+1}'))
#print (df.head())


N = 200
df1 = df.groupby('Column 100').apply(lambda x:x.sample(N)).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df1.head())

print (len(df1))
3000
```